# how do I keep a certain number of elements in an array?

Tags: php, array-push

How do I keep a certain number of elements in an array?

```
function test($var)
{
    if(is_array($_SESSION['myarray']) {
        array_push($_SESSION['myarray'], $var);
    }
}

test("hello");
```

I just want to keep 10 elements in array `$a`. So when I call `test($var)` it should push this value to array but keep the number to 10 by removing some elements from top of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
function test($var) {
    if (is_array($_SESSION['myarray']) {
        array_push($_SESSION['myarray'], $var);
        if (count($_SESSION['myarray']) > 10) {
            $_SESSION['myarray'] = array_slice($_SESSION['myarray'], -10);
        }
    }
}
```

If there a more than 10 values in the array after adding the new one, take just the last 10 values.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (count($_SESSION['myarray'] > 10)
{
    array_shift($_SESSION['myarray']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_shift

```
if(count($_SESSION['myarray']) == 11))
    array_shift($_SESSION['myarray']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($_SESSION["myarray"]) == 10)
{
 $_SESSION["myarray"][9] = $var;
}
else
{
 $_SESSION["myarray"][] = $var
}
```

That should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_10 (&$data, $value)
{
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        $data = array();
    }

    $count = array_push($data, $value);

    if ($count > 10) {
        array_shift($data);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$data = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    array_10($data, $i);
    print_r($data);
}
```